# Would a person split in half if entering a portal to a "mirrored world"?

Tags: gravity, wormholes

I tried making the title worded as good as possible, but let me explain some more:

SPOILER FOR STRANGER THINGS SEASON 4

In episode seven they climb a rope up into the portal and when they enter the other side they fall down because the other side is in the "upside down". Would they not theoretically get stuck in the middle or split in two? Wouldn't the gravity from each world start tugging?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The force of gravity on one's own body weight pulling in opposite directions is not nearly enough to split someone in half. Note that this is basically what happens when you grab a pull-up bar and hang by your arms - the force of gravity pulls your body down, which is resisted by an exactly equal and opposite force pulling you up. The forces holding your body together can very easily handle such strains - it doesn't even hurt, much less tear your body in half. It would take *many* times your own body weight worth of force pulling in opposite directions to do such a thing.

Comment: To add to this answer, in the show the force of gravity keeps it stable by pulling against both ends of the rope, but once one of the gang starts climbing up the rope, suddenly the forces are unbalanced and it should've fallen unless someone on the other side held onto the rope to balance the forces.